# Local Hard disk IO of robpcopy on copying file across remote PC

Tags: windows, robocopy

Robocopy is running in local machine in india and files are copied between remote machines in USA . command is indiamachine> robocopy \usamachine1\src \usamachine2\dest .in this scenario does files get copied from usamachine1 --> India machine ----> usamachine2 ? And if it is done via india machine then all files comes to processor memory or to local disk.

Comment: What do you think?  What happens when you test and observe this robocopy job?